# How to read the in-memory (kernel) partition table of /dev/sda?

Tags: linux, kernel, partition, block-device

I accidentally overwrote my /dev/sda partition table with GParted ([full story on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167872/almost-formatted-my-main-disk-with-gparted-is-it-safe-to-reboot)). Since I haven't rebooted yet and my filesystem is still perfectly usable, I was told I might be able to recover the partition table from in-kernel memory. Is that possible? If so, how do I recover it and restore it?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `/sys` filesystem.

`/sys` is a fake filesystem dynamically generated by the kernel & kernel drivers.
In this specific case you can go to `/sys/block/sda` and you will see a directory for each partition on the drive. There are 2 specific files in those folders you need, `start` and `size`. `start` contains the offset from the beginning of the drive, and `size` is the size of the partition. Just delete the partitions and recreate them with the exact same starts and sizes as found in `/sys`.

For example this is what my drive looks like:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      133119       65536   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *      133120   134340607    67103744    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       134340608   974675967   420167680   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4       974675968   976773167     1048600   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

And this is what I have in `/sys/block/sda`:

```
sda1/
 start: 2048
 size: 131072
sda2/
 start: 133120
 size: 134207488
sda3/
 start: 134340608
 size: 840335360
sda4/
 start: 974675968
 size: 2097200
```

*I have tested this to verify information is accurate after modifying the partition table on a running system*

Comment: Sometimes when I upvote a question, it means "hey this was handy". Your upvote is more like "this saved my skin". Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a `/dev/sdb/start`. Has it been renamed to `ext_range`? Kernel: `4.8.15-1-MANJARO`

Comment: @TomHale it's `/sys/block/sdb/start`, not `/dev/sdb/start`

Comment: Sorry, I quoted the wrong directory. I have a `stat` there, but no `start`.

Comment: When re-creating the partitions, I recommend usind `fdisk` as it allows to enter the number of sectors directly and you can check values before writing to disk. I successfully restored a disk by: creating first partition, accepting being, then entering "+size" (from above) for end, second partition entering `start` from /sys... and "+size" again and so on... Check the size of the partitions before writing the new table. Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

I made a script to help solve this problem, with **NO WARRANTY**.
(but I tested on my virtual machine)

Running the following script, with damaged HD at first parameter, as in:

```
user@host:~$ ./repart.sh sda
```

Content of `repart.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "unit: sectors" 
for i in /sys/block/$1/$1?/; do
    printf '/dev/%s : start=%d, size=%d, type=XX\n' "$(basename $i)" "$(<$i/start)" "$(<$i/size)"
done
```

The output is a sfdisk format. But **caution**, this file has to be modified to be used. At the extended partition type=5, increase the size, using all logical space plus space between start of extended and start of first logical partition.

```
unit: sectors
/dev/sda1 : start=63, size=2040192, type=XX
/dev/sda2 : start=2040255, size=20482875, type=XX
/dev/sda3 : start=22523130, size=19197675, type=XX
/dev/sda4 : start=41720805, size=2, type=XX
/dev/sda5 : start=41720868, size=208782, type=XX
```

You have to change the **type**, from XX to number of partition type. Put the **bootable** partition at first line.

```
unit: sectors
/dev/sda1 : start=63, size=2040192, type=83, bootable
/dev/sda2 : start=2040255, size=20482875, type=83
/dev/sda3 : start=22523130, size=19197675, type=fd
/dev/sda4 : start=41720805, size=208845, type=5
/dev/sda5 : start=41720868, size=208782, type=82
```

Apply this changes

```
cat repart.sfdisk | sfdisk -f /dev/sda
```

Reread partition tables

```
partprobe 
/sbin/blockdev --rereadpt
```

Reinstall grub

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: Make sure to use the "-u B" switch for sfdisk and be careful, you might have to adjust the values in repart.sfdisk (divide them by two usually), if sfdisk counts in blocks sizes (check for "Units = blocks of 1024 bytes" in the "sudo sfdisk -u B -l /dev/sda") other than 512 bytes (usually 1024 nowadays).

Comment: I misread at first: by Id=5 you mean partition type 5, which is sda4, not sda5. Furthermore, in my case ls -d /sys/block/sda/sda* gives me only sda1 and sda5, so it seems that the container is missing.

Comment: you shouldn't parse ls; use find instead

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)?  It can scan the disk and recover lost partition tables, even after you've rebooted.

It's available pre-packaged for Debian and presumably for Ubuntu too. Probably other distros.

If you're booting a gparted CD it's probably worth checking to see if it's pre-installed on that.

Comment: Yes, he did. Just check the link of the OP (askUbuntu)